# Time Countdown working in Chrome but not safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I've got a topbar with a countdown on it. It works fine on chrome and firefox but I just realised it doesn't seem to work in safari.
This is the code:

```
<div class="deadline_Container">
  <div id="clockdiv">
    <span class="deadline_Text">You only have </span>
  <div><span class="days"></span><span  class="smalltext">Days</span></div>
  <div><span class="hours"></span><span  class="smalltext">Hours</span></div>
  <div><span class="minutes"></span><span  class="smalltext">Minutes</span>
</div>
<div class="clockLast"><span class="seconds"></span><span  class="smalltext">Seconds</span></div>
 <span class="deadline_Text2">left to get free delivery!</span></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var deadline = 'Jun 15 2016 23:59:59 GMT';
function time_remaining(endtime){
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
return {'total':t, 'days':days, 'hours':hours, 'minutes':minutes,  'seconds':seconds};
}

function run_clock(id,endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var days_span = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hours_span = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutes_span = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var seconds_span = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function update_clock(){
    var t = time_remaining(endtime);
    days_span.innerHTML = t.days;
    hours_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutes_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    seconds_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
    if(t.total<=0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  update_clock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(update_clock,1000);
}

run_clock('clockdiv',deadline);
</script>
```

Now on safari insteadt of the days,hours,minutes etc. left it says 'NaN' 'an' 'an'. So I assume it's got something to do with the time format?

I've tried setting the time like this:

```
 var deadline = '2016-06-15T23:59:59 GMT +0100';
```

But this didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fundamental issue is parsing strings with the Date constructor. Do not do that, ever. Parsing of strings using the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) is strongly recommended against because it is largely implementation dependent.

As a consequence, you see different results in different browsers. Change:

```
var deadline = 'Jun 15 2016 23:59:59 GMT';
```

to

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 5, 15, 23, 59, 59));
```

And

```
var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
```

to

```
var t = endtime - new Date();
```

Note that `Date.parse(new Date())` will create a new Date, convert it to a string using the implementation–dependent *Date.prototype.toString*, parse that back to a Date, then get the time value.